# XPATH - preserve spaces with getAttribute

Tags: php, xpath

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' name='title[]' value='Some word and another'>
```

**PHP**

```
$title = $xpath->query('//input')->item(0); 
echo $title = $title->getAttribute('value')
```

**RESULT**

> Some

**I NEED TO GET**

> Some word and another

**PROBLEM**
For some reason everything after first space is stripped out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to load it as HTML, so that it allows you to use single quotes:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML("<input type='text' name='title[]' value='Some word and another'>");

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

echo $xpath->query('//input')->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pcs3or